# rsync sobre rsh

Tags: linux, rsync

Estoy intentando configurar `rsync` para que use `rsh` como *transporte*.

He editado el archivo `/etc/pamd./login`:

> #Para no mostrar el mensaje del día, lo comentamos.
>   
>   #session    optional   pam_motd.so motd=/run/motd.dynamic

He creado mi archivo `$HOME/.rhosts`:

```
cat .rhosts
```

> + trauma

```
ls -l .rhosts
```

> -rw------- 1 trauma trauma 9 dic  5 22:38 .rhosts

Y, para evitar mostar el mensaje `lastlogin`, he creado el archivo `.hushlogin`:

```
ls -l .hushlogin
```

> -rw------- 1 trauma trauma 0 dic  5 22:27 .hushlogin

Si intento acceder, funciona *aparentemente* bien, sin mensajes introduciendo *ruido*:

```
rsh 192.168.1.2
```

> trauma@mynas:~$ _

Me muestra lo esperado, mi *prompt* a la espera de órdenes.

Sin embargo, si intento

```
rsync -e rsh Trabajos trauma@192.168.1.2:Backups
```

> protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
>   (see the rsync man page for an explanation)
>   rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(178) [sender=3.1.2]

Haciendo pruebas, veo que si intento usar `rsh` **para ejecutar una orden**:

```
rsh 192.168.1.2 ls
```

Obtengo un *bonito* mensaje de error:

> Authentication failure

#### Pregunto:

1.¿ Porqué me aparece el mensaje `Authentication failure` ?

2.¿ Qué me falta para poder usar `rsync` sobre `rsh` ?

<sub>Nota: **No** es ningún error; **quiero** usar `rsh`, **no** `ssh`</sub>

Comment: Has configurado el pam.d de rsync.d en el servidor destino? prueba esta guia https://www.atlantic.net/hipaa-compliant-cloud-hosting-services/how-to-setup-rsync-daemon-linux-server/

Comment: @tasiaylalo Gracias, pero no es eso lo que quiero. Quiero que cualquier usuario pueda usar `rsync` para hacer *backups* personales, y ejecutarlo como *demonio* no es una opción, ha de poder ejecutarse sobre `rsh`.